# Как правильно передать в CrudRepository в параметре @Param Дату (Spring BOOT)

Tags: mysql, spring, crud

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно передать дату в метод репозитория через @Param.
Если я просто прописываю AND date > '2022-01-01' - то запрос нормально обрабатывается, но как только я хочу передать дату с Сервиса при помощи  @Param("startDate") Date startDate я получаю ошибку.

Репозиторий : FinanceRepository extends CrudRepository

```
@Query("FROM Finance WHERE wallet.id =:walletId " +
            "AND date > ':startDate'")
    List<Finance> findFinanceByWalletDate(@Param("walletId") long walletId,
                                                 @Param("startDate") Date startDate);
```

Сервис :

```
public List<Finance> firstQuarter(Wallet wallet) {
        String str = "2022-03-01";
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = Date.valueOf(str);
        return financeRepository.findFinanceByWalletDate(wallet.getId(),sqlDate);
    }
```

Ошибка :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
```

Comment: Пока что решил данную проблему, через возможности самого JPA.  Например для другого метода, нужно было искать все финансовые операции по кошельку, от начала конкретной даты и до ее конца. List<Finance> findByWalletAndDateBetween(Wallet wallet,LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate); Но конечно хотелось бы разобраться как правильно передать дату в Query.

Comment: Ошибка ни о чем не говорит, лучше добавить подробностей. Почему используете `java.sql.Date` а не `java.util.Date` ? В запросе указание даты должно быть без одинарных кавычек. Вместо `Date` у меня на проекте `java.util.LocalDateTime` и все работает.

Comment: MrFylypenko
Спасибо большое,  ваш совет помог.  Использовал java.util.Date и убрал кавычки все заработало.  Изначально я пробовал и LocalDate и LocalDateTime но так как проблема была в не нужных кавычках в запросе - искал проблему в другом месте.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно использовать кавычки в имени параметра при написании запроса в `@Query` при использовании поименованного параметра с `@Param`, поэтому вот так должно сработать:

```
@Query("FROM Finance WHERE wallet.id = :walletId AND date > :startDate")
List<Finance> findFinanceByWalletDate(@Param("walletId") long walletId,
                                      @Param("startDate") Date startDate);
```

Всю необходимую информацию о правилах использования `@Param` с `@Query` можно найти с примерами в [официальной документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters) spring-data-jpa по этой теме.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("FROM Finance WHERE wallet.id =:walletId " +
        "AND date > :startDate")
List<Finance> findFinanceTEST(@Param("walletId") long walletId,
                                      @Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate);
```

Действительно проблема была в лишних кавычках, так же использовал LocalDateTime и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь :)